# How to/Can I populate <form:select> with List<Object[]>?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I'm passing `List<Object[]>` to my view i.e `jsp`. And want to populate my `<form:select>` tag.
Suppose I have **`List<Object[]> states`**
what I tried is

```
<form:options items"${states}" itemValue="0" itemLabel="1">
```

also

```
<form:options items"${states}" itemValue="states[0]" itemLabel="states[1]">
```

But no Luck coz `java.lang.Object` does not have properties like **0/1** or **states[0]/states[1]**.

One way is, in Controller convert it to `Map`.
Can I directly use this in my jsp?

Answer (score 0):

I know just a little bit Spring MVC, so i’m not sure that i’ve understand completely your question, but the first thing that i can see is that you are getting the object teaking it from the ModelMap using his name and not using his key

Comment: in `Model` key  name is same as its object name.

Comment: Give a look at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/99218-customize-itemvalue-in-form-option